# Is it possible to limit/paginate the number of builds shown in the "Build History" page?

Tags: jenkins

Having a global view like http://build.kde.org/view/All/builds is very helpful but since it's showing jobs since 1.5 years ago it takes ages to load (the browser uses 100% for a few minutes). Is it possible to configure that page so it paginates every 100 builds? Or at least, just to show the last 100 builds?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to paginate views in jenkins for now.
One thing you can do is split you big view to many small views (hand pagination I guess).

Comment: Can't believe this is not implemented in 2017.

Comment: in 2020, and still, it's not there